# Generate .prettierrc from vscode settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Title pretty much says it all. Is there a way to generate .prettierrc from VSCode settings?
There is a tab in the Settings > Extensions > Prettier that you can edit and view prettier

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that? Configuring Prettier's code style options using the extension's setting is a legacy feature. Generally, it's not recommended to use it.

It shouldn't be difficult to write `.prettierrc` manually as Prettier has very few options.